# PHP: IF condition

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there any difference between following two IF conditions?

```
if ($insert_id)
{
..
}



if($insert_id != NULL)
{
..
}
```

Actually a function returns the mysql insert id, and i want to check if the function returned id or not.

Comment: mysql function return boolean FALSE on error, and other thigns on success. They should never be returning null.

Comment: @Marc B, so if theres some mysql error and it doesnt return the insert_id, will the first condition true even then? Which method i should use to make sure that condition is true only if an integer (insert_id) is returned. In all other cases it should be false.

Comment: No, it'd still be false, because the failure turned a false. you can explicitly test with `if ($result_from_mysql === FALSE) { ... failure ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no difference.

There would be if you used !== NULL. If it's just != NULL it will also evaluate against false, '' (empty string) or the integer value 0.

The same goes for the first statement, which is short for $insert_id == true which is basically the same as != false or != NULL.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is loosely equal to FALSE, Zero, and an empty string.

[Study this table to learn about comparisons.](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Basically,

```
$value = NULL;

if($value == FALSE) // True
if($value == '') // True
if($value == 0) // True
while...
if($value === FALSE) // False
if($value === '') // False
if($value === 0) // False
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `$insert_id` belongs to a resultset returned by a `mysql_query`, then use the first one:

```
if ($insert_id)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($insert_id))
{

}

if($insert_id > 0)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the php language,you not need return an expression booleana(what is correct). 
any something different of: 0,false,null and ""(empty string) is parsed as true

Answer (score 0):

For what you're trying to do there is no difference.

Basically what you're trying to do is see if the variable is set.
Since any non-zero expression is essentially true, if there is a value it will 
evaluate as such.

The only time it would matter is if you were specifically checking for a NULL value.